# django post method not working after passing parameter in url

Tags: django, post, django-models, django-forms

I am learning Django and learning it hardway. I don't completely understand what is happening when I am posting my data from template. I have a models class Person that defines fields in the table. I am using form to display informaiton about a person and I can view the information of a particular person but I cannot save the same information. When I click submit, I get the error page not found. I don't understand why person is appended twice in the url at all. This is all a little confusing. I hope some one can help me understand where I am going wrong. 
Request URL: http://devops:8000/cms/person/person
Here is my code:

forms.py:

```
class PersonView(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Person
        fields = ['FirstName','LastName','Address']
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('cms',
    url(r'^workflowdetail/(?P<id>\d+)$', 'views.person',name='cms'),
)
```

views.py:

```
def person(request, id):
    person= get_object_or_404(Person, pk=id)
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = Person(instance=person)
    else:
        form = Person(request.POST,instance=person)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    return render(request, 'person.html', {'form': form, 'id': id})
```

person.html

```
<form action="person" role="form" method="post">
    {% bootstrap_form form %}
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `action` in the form is incorrect. When you use `person`, this does not mean it will use the `person` view, it means that the form will be submitted to the relative url `person`.

You can use the `url` tag to get the correct url:

```
<form action="{% url 'cms' id %}" role="form" method="post">
```

Now I'll try to explain where the double `person/person` in the url comes from:

If you start at, say, `/cms/person/`, then the relative url `person` is `/cms/person/person/`. If you start at `/cms/person/1`, then the relative url `person` is also `/cms/person/person/`. Since you don't have a url pattern for this, you get a 404 error.

However, if you start at `/cms/person/1/`, then the relative url `person` is `/cms/person/1/person/`

For that reason, you might find it easier to use a trailing slash in your urls, e.g.

```
r'^workflowdetail/(?P<id>\d+)/$
```

If you do that, you won't actually need the `action` attribute in your form tag at all.

```
<form role="form" method="post">
```

Comment: I did try that before and I get this error.  

NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'workflow' with arguments '(u'2',)' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []

Comment: You must have tried something slightly different - my code wouldn't cause an error containing 'workflow'. Note that I used `'cms'` because you have `name='cms'` in the url pattern.

Comment: It was a copy error I did. Your solution was correct and worked. I couldn't use the original code and tried to edit it. But your solution was perfect. I used the wrong name instead of cms and now it works.